# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku' even though django-heroku is installed

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to run `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook` from my project directory, within a virtual environment. This command was previously working, but now no longer, and I believe the issue must be with some package version conflicts.

I have a virtual environment with the following packages installed:

```
Package              Version
-------------------- -----------
appnope              0.1.3
argon2-cffi          21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings 21.2.0
asgiref              3.5.2
asttokens            2.0.5
attrs                21.4.0
backcall             0.2.0
backports.zoneinfo   0.2.1
beautifulsoup4       4.11.1
bleach               5.0.0
cffi                 1.15.0
debugpy              1.6.0
decorator            5.1.1
defusedxml           0.7.1
dj-database-url      0.5.0
Django               4.0.4
django-extensions    3.1.5
django-heroku        0.3.1
django-on-heroku     1.1.2
entrypoints          0.4
executing            0.8.3
fastjsonschema       2.15.3
gunicorn             20.1.0
importlib-resources  5.7.1
ipykernel            6.13.0
ipython              8.3.0
ipython-genutils     0.2.0
ipywidgets           7.7.0
jedi                 0.18.1
Jinja2               3.1.2
jsonschema           4.5.1
jupyter              1.0.0
jupyter-client       7.3.1
jupyter-console      6.4.3
jupyter-core         4.10.0
jupyterlab-pygments  0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets   1.1.0
MarkupSafe           2.1.1
matplotlib-inline    0.1.3
mistune              0.8.4
nbclient             0.6.3
nbconvert            6.5.0
nbformat             5.4.0
nest-asyncio         1.5.5
notebook             6.4.11
numpy                1.22.3
packaging            21.3
pandocfilters        1.5.0
parso                0.8.3
pexpect              4.8.0
pickleshare          0.7.5
pip                  22.1
prometheus-client    0.14.1
prompt-toolkit       3.0.29
psutil               5.9.0
psycopg2             2.9.3
psycopg2-binary      2.9.3
ptyprocess           0.7.0
pure-eval            0.2.2
pycparser            2.21
Pygments             2.12.0
pyparsing            3.0.9
pyrsistent           0.18.1
python-dateutil      2.8.2
pyzmq                22.3.0
qtconsole            5.3.0
QtPy                 2.1.0
scipy                1.8.1
Send2Trash           1.8.0
setuptools           49.2.1
six                  1.16.0
soupsieve            2.3.2.post1
sqlparse             0.4.2
stack-data           0.2.0
terminado            0.15.0
tinycss2             1.1.1
tornado              6.1
traitlets            5.2.1.post0
wcwidth              0.2.5
webencodings         0.5.1
whitenoise           6.1.0
widgetsnbextension   3.6.0
zipp                 3.8.0
```

`django-heroku` is installed as well as `psycopg2`, but somehow I still keep getting this error. I tried everything on Stackoverflow (and even reinstaled Python altogether), but nothing fixed this issue.

Python version: `Python 3.8.9`
Machine: `Macbook Pro with M1 chip`

Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

**Update:**

Somehow what solved the issue was running `./manage.py shell_plus --notebook` instead of `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook`. I don't understand why this resolved the problem, and if there is a way to get the command to run with `python`, too, that'd be great! Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Are you getting this error _locally_ or on Heroku? In the first case, I'm not sure why the [tag:heroku] tag is relevant. In the second case, what you have installed locally is irrelevant. What matters is what is installed on _Heroku_, which is driven by the dependencies you have declared in your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. Assuming this is an issue on Heroku, please [edit] your question and show us those files.

Comment: Note: you should not have both `django-heroku` and `django-on-heroku`. [`django-heroku` is deprecated](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku): "This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only." [`django-on-heroku`](https://pypi.org/project/django-on-heroku/) is a maintained fork: "This has been forked from django-heroku because it was abandoned and then renamed to django-on-heroku because old project has been archived." Uninstall `django-heroku` locally, remove it from your dependencies file, then change `django_heroku` to `django_on_heroku` in your settings file.

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular: "**Post the question and respond to feedback** After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!"

Comment: I get this issue locally. I also tried only having `django-on-heroku`, but that didn't solve the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run:

```
pip install django-heroku
```

you need to install **psycopg2** by running:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

This is the only way to install it. If this doesn't fix the errors. I think you need to share your heroku settings in your **settings.py** file.

Comment: What makes you think this is the solution? OP already has `django-heroku` (which is no longer supported and should _not_ be used) and `psycopg2` installed in their local environment.

Comment: 2 months ago I try to develop a Django application with heroku I face the same error like this one he describe. I follow this solution and it's worked. My friend @Habibi send me the Github repo via WhatsApp because he tried but fails.

Comment: Again, OP _already has both those libraries listed in their dependencies_

Comment: Me too. He have installed them and add them into a **requirements.txt** file after I installed all of these in to my virtual environment I run this command from my cmd: **pip freeze** to show all the dependencies and run: **pip freeze > requirements.txt** and did **heroku login:** and the push everything to **heroku**

Comment: Yes, I've tried this multiple times and it didn't work. My `settings.py` file should be fine, too, as everything used to work before.

Comment: Did you try exactly how @Chris is telling you to do ?